# How to get list of modified objects in Entity Framework 5

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework-5

I'm binding list of `entities` to a data grid view like this:

```
var orders = context.Order.ToList();

BindingList<Order> orderList = new BindingList<Order>(orders);

dataGridView1.DataSource = orderList;
```

User can edit or add new directly on datagridview. When user click `Save` button, in order to optimize performance, I want to retrieve list of entities that has been changed/new to perform insert/update. How can I achieve this?

**EDIT** Define add new row to gridview:

```
BindinList<Order> orders = (BindingList<Order>)dataGridView1.Datasource;

order.Add(new Order());
```

**EDIT 2** Solve:

```
BindinList<Order> orders = (BindingList<Order>)dataGridView1.Datasource;

Order order = new Order();

context.Order.Add(order);

order.Add(order);
```

Answer (score 49, accepted):

```
List<Object> modifiedOrAddedEntities = context.ChangeTracker.Entries()
 .Where(x => x.State == System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified 
        || x.State == System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Added)
 .Select(x=>x.Entity).ToList();
```

When binding EF entities to a `DataGridView` it is often preferable to create an `IBindingList` from the `DbSet.Local` `ObservableCollection`. This way you get two way databinding and your new entities are automatically added to the context when adding via `BindingSource.Add()` or `IBindingList.Add()`. The simplest way to get this working, once properly bound, is to set `DataGridView.AllowUserToAddRows` to true and new rows the users enter will be new entities Added to the context.

```
context.Orders.Load();
BindingList<Order> bindingList = context.Orders.Local.ToBindingList();
BindingSource ordersBindingSource = new BindingSource();
ordersBindingSource.DataSource = bindingList;
dataGridView1.DataSource = ordersBindingSource ;
```

`System.Data.Entity` must be referenced to use `.ToBindingList()` and you must be using EF4.1 or greater.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Your code can get list of modified entities but it can't get list of new entities. I provide code that use to add new entities. Can you help me to figured out?

Comment: @DoanCuong, see additional answer detail.

Comment: Excuse me, but would you please show me how to implement the `BindingSource.Add()` or `IBingdingList.Add()`? And one more thing, there are no `ToBindingList()` function on `dbset.local`. The only way to do it is using 
`var bindingList = new BindingList<Orders>(context.Orders.Local.ToList());`

Comment: @DoanCuong, answer updated. It can be more complex than I have shown depending on your entity but with some research you should be able to work it out.