# Get number of rows deleted and number of rows edited by DbContext.SaveChanges()

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I use entity framework 6.1 with Code First approach. 
When I use [**DbContext.SaveChanges()**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext.savechanges%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) as the result I can get

> The number of objects written to the underlying database.

But is that possible to get advanced statistics: number of rows deleted, number of rows edited, number of rows added?

My supergoal is to get per-Entity staticstics.

Maybe before actually calling SaveChanges()..

Comment: I think the answer in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17463415/how-to-get-list-of-modified-objects-in-entity-framework-5) will help you

Comment: Thx. I've missed that one

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
var modifiedCount = dbContext.ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(x => x.State == System.Data.EntityState.Modified).Count()
```

The above line of code can be used to fetch the modified entries, and similarly you can fetch the deleted and added too..

But you have to execute these lines of code before you call SaveChanges().

Comment: It should be `System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified` instead of `System.Data.EntityState.Modified`. At least for EF6.

_Edit suggestion from my part was rejected, but sofar I can see, the author possibly will never edit this... no activity since 2014... and on the other hand my comment probably will disappear some day and someone else might suggest the same? Weird reviewing system. But to follow the reviewers reasonings, now shared as a comment ^^_

Answer (score 1):

You could use `db.GetChangeSet()`. This will contains three lists:

```
var deletes = db.GetChangeSet().Deletes;
var updates = db.GetChangeSet().Updates;
var inserts = db.GetChangeSet().Inserts;
var all = db.GetChangeSet().All;
```

This can be done before you submit the changes to the database.

Considering having a table called country

```
db.Tblcountries.InsertOnSubmit(
   new Tblcountry(){FkRegionId=1,CountryCode="US",Name="USA"});
var result= db.GetChangeSet().All.ToList();
```

The `All` list and the `Insert` list will contain this list:

```
PkCountryId Name CountryCode FkRegionId 
0           USA  US          1
```

Reference:

- [DataContext.GetChangeSet Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.getchangeset%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: `GetChangeSet()` is for Linq-to-SQL (the predecessor to Linq-to-Entities and Entity Framework), it isn't present in Entity Framework that the OP is asking about.

Answer (score -2):

According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext.savechanges%28v=vs.103%29.aspx), the return value of DbContext.SaveChanges is

The number of objects written to the underlying database.

So what you see is only possible, when no entities needed to be saved to the database.