# Updating entity updates also another entity

Tags: entity-framework

I have a table that its PK is made of 2 columns (ID and PK2).
The following code, gives me 2 different entities.
But when I change one of them, the other is also changed.

```
var entity1 = _database.TABLE.SingleOrDefault(s => s.ID == entity.Id && s.PK2 != 100);
var entity2 = _database.TABLE.SingleOrDefault(s => s.ID == entity.Id && s.PK2 == 100);
entity1.Name = "ABCD"; // entity2.Name is also set to "ABCD".
```

I would love to know Why is this happening and I can I prevent it?

Does EF has a problem working with 2 columns PK?

Thanks.

Comment: EF has no problem when working with 2 columns PK. In your codes, you need to modify `multiple entries` in the table. The database DOESN'T know that when 1 entry modified, the another entry should be modified too. You need to implement it by yourself, to connect the relationships between those entries.

Comment: I want just one of the entities to be updated. My problem is that for some reason both of them are updated. And that is the objects entity1 and entity2, before I save changes.

Comment: I think you need to debug it. Maybe you can trace those modified entries by [this thread information](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17463497/419348). And, sorry to mis-understand your question.

Comment: Are both columns "real" primary keys? That is: does the database primary key consist of both columns? Or did you only map them as primary key in the EF model?